# Book suggestions alongside Adventures in Stochastic Processes by Resnick

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I am currently taking a SP course following Resnick's book. Are there any other books with exercises (and possibly solutions) I could also look at?

Comment: ([tag:reference-request]) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags). (This is also mentioned in the tag-excerpt, which is shown when you are adding this tag.)

Answer (score 1):

There exists a vast literature on the topic of stochastic processes; without further information on your interests and your level it is therefore hard to recommend any books.

However, if you are looking for a book with a [solution manual](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/index.html), I can recommend *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling and Lothar Partzsch. As the title suggests, the book focusses on Brownian motion and stochastic integration with respect to Brownian motion.

A broader variety of topics is discussed in *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Daniel Revuz and Marc Yor; in particular they give an introduction to Markov and Feller processes, martingale theory and stochastic integration with respect to (continuous) martingales.